# Manually Download and Place a golang mod file

Tags: go, goproxy

I am in China and I am compiling a program on linux. The problem is that golang related things are blocked in China. I have tried many proxies but I can't find a solutuion. Can some one please explain me where to manually put this file. I can open it in browser but i don' know where to place it.

go: github.com/onsi/gomega@v1.17.0: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/onsi/gomega/@v/v1.17.0.mod": dial tcp 172.217.163.49:443: i/o timeout
go: downloading github.com/pkg/errors v0.9.1

Comment: why you don't just use VPN

Comment: Using express VPN but it blocks the docker network. The process stopped before reaching at this point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an example to use a proxy, you can refer to this [repo](https://github.com/goproxy/goproxy.cn)  which is used for china Gophers and you can check the documentation on this [site](https://goproxy.io/). you may use another proxy link but the method is the same.

- **macOS or Linux**

Open your terminal and execute

```
$ export GO111MODULE=on
$ export GOPROXY=https://goproxy.cn
```

or

```
$ echo "export GO111MODULE=on" >> ~/.profile
$ echo "export GOPROXY=https://goproxy.cn" >> ~/.profile
$ source ~/.profile
```

done.

- **Windows**

Open your PowerShell and execute

```
C:\> $env:GO111MODULE = "on"
C:\> $env:GOPROXY = "https://goproxy.cn"
```

if you want to make exceptions you can try:-

```
# Set the GOPROXY environment variable
export GOPROXY=https://goproxy.io,direct
# Set environment variable allow bypassing the proxy for specified repos (optional)
export GOPRIVATE=git.mycompany.com,github.com/my/private
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ export GO111MODULE=on
$ export GOPROXY=https://goproxy.cn
```

This works for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).