# timeout when I try to install go dependencies

Tags: linux, go, visual-studio-code, terminal, project

I try to run my golang project with `go run main.go`.
I receive:

```
go: downloading github.com/package
main.go:13:2: github.com/package: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/package": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp: lookup http on x.x.x.x:x: read udp x.x.x.x:x->x.x.x.x:x: i/o timeout
```

Help me please resolve this problem.

Comment: It looks like your DNS is not resolving `proxy.golang.org`. This could be due to your environment (developing in a container?) or external factors (China is known to [block `proxy.golang.org`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71541097/11810946)). Please provide more details (e.g. can you resolve other domain names and ideally pick a real package to reduce the severity of redaction).

Answer (score 12):

export GOPROXY=direct
and relaunch, seems like proxy.golang.org have some difficulties recently
HTH

Answer (score 0):

`GOPROXY=direct` is one way.

The other one works for me is that adding `nameserver 1.1.1.1` to the `/etc/resolv.conf` since I'm installing it under a VM rather than my PC.

It looks like this:

```
# Generated by the VMware NetworkManager
search localdomain
nameserver 172.16.100.1 <- It's used by the proxy which is not ideal

nameserver 1.1.1.1
```